# Is it possible to get the string in Chrome message box via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, automation, webdriver

The screenshot shows that the Chrome is controlled by webdriver. The message is shown in the red box.

I'm wondering if it is possible to run a piece of JavaScript code to access the message in the red box.

Any suggestions are welcome.
Thank you

Ivan
[image]